# Error when istall connect-sqlite3 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-pre-gyp

I have a problem when installing `npm install connect-sqlite3 --save` on the CentOS 7 server.

I got an error below:

> npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to
> @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is
> deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in
> the future npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no
> longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please
> upgrade asap.

When I try to upgrade `node-pre-gyp` using the command `npm install @mapbox/node-pre-gyp --save`, I still got the error message.

Could anyone help me?